# Clustering Apache Tomcat6

Tags: java, apache, tomcat6, mod-proxy, cluster-computing

I've got a Java Enterprise Web Application which uses Tomcat6+Struts+Hibernate+MySql. at the time being it's publicly up and running on a single server. In order to performance issues we should move the application to a clustered environment. Anyhow I wanna use Tomcat6 clustering as below:

- A Load Balancing machine including a web server (Apache+mod_proxy) as front-end
- Some application server machines, each one running a tomcat6 instance
- A session management back-end
- And finally a db server

something like this

[image: this]

The load balancer machine receives all the requests and depending on the balancing algorithm redirects them to the respective tomacat6 machine. After doing the business part, the response is returned to the webserver and at the end to the user. In this scenario the front-end machine processes all the requests and responses so it'd be a bottleneck point in the application.

In Apache Tomcat clustering, is there a way to load balancing mechanism and web servers? I mean putting a load balancer in the front end and leave the request/response processing part to multiple web servers.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat has no support for clustering built in. What happens is that the load balancer distributes requests, so the various Tomcat instances don't need to know what is happening.

What you have to do is to make sure your *application* can handle it. For example, you must be aware that caches can be stale.

Say instance 1 has object X in it's cache and X is modified by a request processed on instance 2. The cache in instance 2 will be correct, the cache from instance 1 will be stale now.

The solution is to use a cache which supports clustering or disable caching for instances which can be modified. But that doesn't matter to Tomcat.

Comment: worrying about caching is a separated problem. What I wanna know here is, Would this single web-server machine tolerate this amount of load?

Comment: Do you have any numbers about what we are talking? How many accesses (Page Views, Page Impressions, How many users?)

Comment: @SJ Jafari: How would I know? How many visitors are you going to have? How complex is each request? How powerful is your computer, CPU, RAM, disks, network?

Comment: @Aaron, @khmarbais, Sorry, I kinda misspelled my words here, I'm pretty sure the single web server won't tolerate my estimated load. the question is how can I establish multiple web servers? 
btw I got about 400 online users now but it'll grow to about 10000, sessions are kinda heavy including complex objects.

Comment: to make sure I'm in the right path, Does the load of requests and responses lay on Apache http front-end, or on the tomcat instances?

Comment: To spread the load, get a dedicated load balancer and put that in front of the Tomcats. This thing is dumb but can always handle the amount of requests since it just forwards them to a Tomcat instance. As soon as the Tomcat instances are no longer able to handle the load, add another box with another Tomcat instance.

Comment: You will also want to look into "cloud computing" because it handles all this for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing